# Unable to set Rails model attribute from console or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm new to Rails and am working on getting an application set up in Rails 4.2.4. I have a model called `List` that looks like the following in the database (PostgresQL):

```
List(id: integer, user_id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, friendly_name: string)
```

and in List.rb:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name, :friendly_name
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :items
end
```

I am trying to modify the `name` attribute from a controller action:

```
def save_name
    ...
    list_to_edit = List.find(params[:id].to_i)
    list_to_edit.name = params[:name]
    list_to_edit.save!
    ...
end
```

But the changes are not being persisted. I have confirmed that params[:name] and list_to_edit are not nil. When I try to change the attribute in the Rails console like this:

```
> l = List.last
> l.name = 'TestName'
> l.save!
```

I don't see any errors. After executing the above commands and executing `l.name` I do see `TestName`. When I type `l` or `List.last`, however I still see

```
#<List id: 29, user_id: 17, name: nil, created_at: "2015-11-07 18:55:04", updated_at: "2015-11-07 18:55:04", friendly_name: nil>
```

What do I need to do to set the name attribute of a `List`? I can post any additional file content if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few more things it looks like all I needed to do was remove `name` from the array being passed to `attr_accessor` in List.rb. I believe when I was trying to change the list name with `my_list.name = 'something'` I was modifying the instance variable, not the attribute stored in the database.